# Packet for query is too large (1134 > 1024)

Tags: mysql, linux

Packet for query is too large (1134 > 1024), this shown always , and max_allow_packet was configured up to 1024 , either raise ulimit 'open files' and MySQL 'open_files_limit' to 1024000, but this error still shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved by increase the open files limit for a non-root user
 `$ ulimit -n`
if it 1024 byte, then it should be increased by typing
 `$ ulimit -n 2048`
but it is not a permanent solution if a system reboot, ulimit will get back to default value.To make it permanent follow below link.
As root, I can change that limit to whatever I want, up or down. It doesn't even seem to care about the supposedly system-wide limit in /proc/sys/fs/file-max

`#cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
    188897
    #ulimit -n 188898
    #ulimit -n 
    188898`

For more information 
https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase `max_allowed_packet` value and not ulimit, try the following in the terminal, before executing the query:

```
mysqld --max_allowed_packet=20M
```

Or you can even set the following in `my.cnf` file and restart `MySQL`:

```
max_allowed_packet=20M
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) MySQL documentation for it.